# Alternative of summarise() function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
food_consumption %>% 
   group_by(food_category) %>% 
   summarise(mod= lm(co2_emmission ~ consumption))
```

After runing this code I get the folowing error

> Error: Column `mod` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 12

How can I make it right, and get the regression results for each catagory?

Answer (score 5):

We can wrap the output of `lm` model in a `list` as it have many components and `summarise` wants to return with a length of 1 for each group

```
library(dplyr)
food_consumption %>% 
     group_by(food_category) %>%
     summarise(mod= list(lm(co2_emmission ~ consumption)))
```

---

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, can use `condense`, which would automatically return a `list`

```
food_consumption %>% 
     group_by(food_category) %>%
     condense(mod= lm(co2_emmission ~ consumption))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(cyl) %>%
     summarise(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ gear)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl mod   
#  <dbl> <list>
#1     4 <lm>  
#2     6 <lm>  
#3     8 <lm>
```

Or with `condense`

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   condense(mod = lm(mpg ~ gear))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise:  cyl
#    cyl mod   
#  <dbl> <list>
#1     4 <lm>  
#2     6 <lm>  
#3     8 <lm>
```

In order to get the coefficients

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>%
    condense(mod = lm(mpg ~ gear), Coef = coef(mod))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise:  cyl
#    cyl mod    Coef     
#  <dbl> <list> <list>   
#1     4 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
#2     6 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
#3     8 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
```

Or with `mutate` and `map`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ gear))) %>% 
    mutate(Coef = map(mod, coef))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl mod    Coef     
#  <dbl> <list> <list>   
#1     4 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
#2     6 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
#3     8 <lm>   <dbl [2]>
```

Or another option is `nest` and then `map` over the `list`

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    nest %>% 
    transmute(mod = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ gear, data = .x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl mod   
#  <dbl> <list>
#1     6 <lm>  
#2     4 <lm>  
#3     8 <lm>
```

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful... but now getting the coefficients of all model from the list is a bit difficult. Can you help? plz